# How can I detect the characters/the number in the picture?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, python-tesseract

I want to detect the text on the image, in this case the '58505'. I have problems to detect that with tesseract. The preprocess will do by opencv. My problem is to detect the last image (see below), because there is a lot of noise.

How can I detect the characters/the number in the pictures?

[image]

[image]

My **first** Idea:

1. Covert it in grayscale

```python
cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

2. Afters that I will convert it to Black/White

```python
cv2.threshold(tmp_img, 95, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

3. Then I remove the noise.

```python
def noise_removal(image, kernel_size_1, kernel_size_2):
    kernel = np.ones(kernel_size_1, np.uint8)
    image = cv2.dilate(image,kernel,iterations=1)
    kernel = np.ones(kernel_size_2, np.uint8)
    image = cv2.erode(image,kernel,iterations=1)
    image = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    image = cv2.medianBlur(image,3)
    return image

noise_removal(img, (1,1),(1,1))
```

4. At last, I use tesseract to get the string of the file.

```python
orc_result = pytesseract.image_to_string(noiserev_img, config = custom_config)
```

That doesn't work, because there is a lot of noise in my opinion. Only 50% will detect right.

My **second** Idea is the following:

1. Convert it in grayscale

```python
cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

2. Remove noise

```python
def noise_removal(image, kernel_size_1, kernel_size_2):
    kernel = np.ones(kernel_size_1, np.uint8)
    image = cv2.dilate(image,kernel,iterations=1)
    kernel = np.ones(kernel_size_2, np.uint8)
    image = cv2.erode(image,kernel,iterations=1)
    image = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    image = cv2.medianBlur(image,3)
    return image

noise_removal(img, (1,1),(1,1))
```

3. Convert it in Black/White

```python
cv2.threshold(tmp_img, 95, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

4. At last, I use tesseract to get the string of the file.

```python
orc_result = pytesseract.image_to_string(noiserev_img, config = custom_config)
```

That result is the same like the result in the first idea.

My **third** and last idea:

1. Covert it in grayscale

```python
cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

2. Afters that I will convert it to Black/White

```python
cv2.threshold(tmp_img, 95, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

3. Then I remove the noise.

```python
def noise_removal(image, kernel_size_1, kernel_size_2):
    kernel = np.ones(kernel_size_1, np.uint8)
    image = cv2.dilate(image,kernel,iterations=1)
    kernel = np.ones(kernel_size_2, np.uint8)
    image = cv2.erode(image,kernel,iterations=1)
    image = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    image = cv2.medianBlur(image,3)
    return image

noise_removal(img, (1,1),(1,1))
```

4. Boundering the image in each character, looks like this:

```python
blur_picked_img = []
for item in bw_picked_img:
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(item,(5,5), 0)
    ctp(blur)
    blur_picked_img.append(blur)
thresh_picked_img = []
for item in blur_picked_img:
    thresh = cv2.threshold(item, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    ctp(thresh)
    thresh_picked_img.append(thresh)
kernal_picked_img = []
for item in thresh_picked_img:
    kernal = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(3,13))
    ctp(kernal)
    kernal_picked_img.append(kernal)
dilate_picked_img = []
for i in range(len(kernal_picked_img)):
    tmp = cv2.dilate(thresh_picked_img[i], kernal_picked_img[i], iterations =1)
    ctp(tmp)
    dilate_picked_img.append(tmp)
cnts_picked_img= []
for i in range(len(dilate_picked_img)):
    tmp = cv2.findContours(dilate_picked_img[i], cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    tmp = tmp[0] if len(tmp) == 2 else tmp[1]
    tmp = sorted(tmp, key = lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[0])
    for c in tmp:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(picked_img[i], (x,y),(x+w, y+h),(36,255,12),2)
    cnts_picked_img.append(tmp)
```

[image]

5. Take each field and remove the noise again and convert it to Black/White
6. At last, I use tesseract to get the string of the file.

```python
orc_result = pytesseract.image_to_string(noiserev_img, config = custom_config)
```

The Problem: The boundering failed. In the first picture the boundering was successful, but not in the second picture.

Comment: The top image is easy, just binarize. The bottom one a nightmare.

Comment: Post the original input images without the bounding boxes

Comment: I post the original pictures in edited post.

Comment: why does the second image look like that? what processing was done to it to make it look like that? I doubt that's an unaltered picture of a real object. if it is, please give details.

Comment: It's a real image, taken by a camera. It's an impact number in metal